# can not convert multidimensional array to single php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a multidimensional php array to a single array.. but having difficulty to do that. My given input is like:

```
array ( 0 => array ('id' => 3,
'text' => 'Name 3',
'children' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'text' => 'Name 4',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 5,
        'text' => 'Name 5',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 6,
            'text' => 'Name 6',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'text' => 'name 7',
  ),
),),)
```

and my expected output is like this:

```
array(3=>'Name 3', 4=>'name 4', 5=>'name 5', 6=>'name 6', 7=>'name 7')
```

I've tried so far as follows:

```
function nestedToSingle($array)
{
    $singleDimArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $item) {

        if (is_array($item)) {

            $singleDimArray = array_merge($singleDimArray, nestedToSingle($item));
        } else {
            $singleDimArray[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $singleDimArray;
}
```

but it giving me output like this:

```
array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 'name 3',  2 => 4,  3 => 'Name 4',  4 => 5,  5 => 'name 5',  6 => 6,  7 => 'name 6',  8 => 7,  9 => 'name 7',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your looping until you find a value that isn't an array and you write that to your `singleDimArray`. And because you are not specifically setting a key it gets the default numerical, incrementing key. So each non-array value gets registered separately.

Try the following where you set `singleDimArray` as a static variable so you can keep on adding to it each time you call the function for the next nested array:

```
function nestedToSingle( $array )
{
    static $singleDimArray = [];
    
    foreach ( $array as $item ) {

        if ( is_array( $item ) ) {
            if ( array_key_exists( 'id', $item ) && array_key_exists( 'text', $item ) ) {
                $singleDimArray[$item['id']] = $item['text'];
            } 
            if ( array_key_exists( 'children', $item ) && is_array( $item['children'] ) ) {
                nestedToSingle( $item['children'] );
            }
        } 
    }

    return $singleDimArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` for this. Its callback function takes the key and value of each leaf node in the structure. Just check for the "text" key and collect each matching value.

```
$names = [];
array_walk_recursive($input, function($value, $key) use (&$names) {
    $key == 'text' && $names[] = $value;
});
```

`use (&$names)` is necessary to get the `$names` array into the function scope.